# xlwings loop causing OS CommandErrors while line-by-line doesn't

Tags: python, excel, macos, xlwings

I am trying to loop through Excel files on a Mac 10.10.5 with xlwings in python in order to save the values only (i.e. not the formulae that create them). Many of the files have been output by automated software, so the typical pandas.read_excel function produces null values for any cells that start with =.

Anyway, if I walk through what's inside the `for` loop, one at a time in ipython, the code works fine. However, what's causing an error is that when the script runs with a loop, whenever it gets to a workbook that hasn't been walked through manually, it produces an error. Here's the script (reduced version in update below):

```
wkbks = [fl for fl in os.listdir(originals_folder) if any([fl.endswith(ext) for ext in ['.xls', 'xlsx']])]
for w_idx, wkbk in enumerate(wkbks):
    if w_idx % 10 == 0:
        print "\t{}/{}".format(w_idx, len(wkbks))

    wb = xw.Book( os.path.join(originals_folder, wkbk) )
    new_wb = xw.Book()
    for sht_idx, sht in enumerate(wb.sheets):
        # look for a pretty wide range (disclaimer: not super robust for really large sheets)
        values = sht.range('A1:HZ1000').value
        df = pd.DataFrame(values)
        rows_to_keep = df.isnull().sum(axis=1) < df.shape[1]
        cols_to_keep = df.isnull().sum(axis=0) < df.shape[0]
        df = df.ix[rows_to_keep, cols_to_keep]

        # add values to new sheet
        if not any([sht.name == sh.name for sh in new_wb.sheets]):
            if sht_idx == 0:
                new_wb.sheets.add(sht.name)
            else:
                new_wb.sheets.add(sht.name, after=wb.sheets[sht_idx-1].name)
        new_wb.sheets[sht.name].range('A1').value = df.values

    new_name = new_wb.name
    new_wb.save() # close to generic name in current location, as filepaths produced an error

    # close newly made workbook
    close_workbook_by_name(xw, new_name)

    # copy newly made workbook to base_folder
    new_fname = [f for f in os.listdir('./') if f.startswith(new_name)][0]
    shutil.copy2(os.path.join('./', new_fname), os.path.join(base_folder, wkbk))

    # remove newly made file from current directory
    os.remove( os.path.join('./', new_fname) )

    # close original workbook
    close_workbook_by_name(xw, wkbk)

    del sht, new_wb, wb, wkbk, shts
```

And here's the error (again, this only happens when it loops to a wkbk that hasn't yet been manually 'walked through' in ipython):

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CommandError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-319-2240e28ae169> in <module>()
     14     shts = wb.sheets
     15     sht_idx = 0
---> 16     for sht in shts:
     17         sht = wb.sheets[sht.name]
     18
...
CommandError: Command failed:
        OSERROR: -1728
        MESSAGE: The object you are trying to access does not exist
        COMMAND: app(pid=8732).workbooks['cwa balance sheet 9.30.2017-5688630b3.xlsx'].count(each=k.worksheet)
```

Any suggestions on the specifics or general strategy here would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

## UPDATE

Reduced script

```
wkbks = [fl for fl in os.listdir(originals_folder) if any([fl.endswith(ext) for ext in ['.xls', 'xlsx']])]
for w_idx, wkbk in enumerate(wkbks):
    wb = xw.Book( os.path.join(originals_folder, wkbk) )
    new_wb = xw.Book()
    for sht_idx, sht in enumerate(wb.sheets):
        pass

    new_wb.save() # close to generic name in current location, as filepaths produced an error

    # close newly made workbook
    book_idx_to_close = [b_idx for b_idx, b in enumerate(xw.books) if b.name.startswith(new_name)]
    if len(book_idx_to_close) > 0:
        book_to_close = xw.books[book_idx_to_close[0]]
        book_to_close.close()
    print "Closed", new_name

    # close original workbook
    book_idx_to_close = [b_idx for b_idx, b in enumerate(xw.books) if b.name.startswith(wkbk)]
    if len(book_idx_to_close) > 0:
        book_to_close = xw.books[book_idx_to_close[0]]
        book_to_close.close()
    print "Closed", wkbk
```

New error:

```
<ipython-input-14-68ed128e9078> in <module>()
     34     if len(book_idx_to_close) > 0:
     35         book_to_close = xw.books[book_idx_to_close[0]]
---> 36         book_to_close.close()
     37     print "Closed", new_name
     38

... 

CommandError: Command failed:
        OSERROR: -50
        MESSAGE: Parameter error.
        COMMAND: app(pid=10100).workbooks[2].close(saving=k.no)
```

The error occurs when a file opens that requires a 'Read Only' access due to some features not being compatible with the current version of Excel. However, after receiving the error, when I retype `book_to_close.close()`, the file closes with no error. Also, there is no error when opening/saving/closing a file that had the same read only access, when I had previously 'walked through' it manually.

I realize this is a different error than the one above, but suspect they may be related (hence why leaving the original post as is above).

Comment: Have you done any debugging? E.g., do you get the error when you remove/comment-out all the extra operations (such as saving it to a new files after the inner loop, creating a DataFrame etc). That is, can you loop through the workbooks and open them without doing anything extra? Please make your example a *minimal* example that produces the error.

Comment: Note that you loop through the sheets, then immediately reassign `sht` to the respective sheet by its name. Why is that? It doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @Evert, good points. I appended an updated script with the resulting error (different error, but possibly related). Please, let me know what you think!

Comment: What `app` are you using to connect to an Excel instance?

Comment: xlwings via ipython (Python 2.7)